# перенос системы на ssd без кабелей

Tags: сеть, хранение-данных, hdd, миграция, ssd

Столкнулся с проблемой после покупки ssd, не знаю как перенести все свои "пожитки" с hdd ноутбука на новый ssd. Проблема в том что у меня нету никаких переходников и взять их негде. Из исходных данных есть hdd, работающий в ноутбуке, новый ssd лежит рядом с ноутбуком, стационарный комп в котором есть 1 sata кабель к которому подключен hdd, комп и ноут соединены сетью, кто что может посоветовать?

Comment: Могу посоветовать таки найти переходник, позволяющий вставить HDD вместо оптического (DVD?) привода, чтобы держать в ноутбуке оба диска сразу. Практичная вещь в целом, да и миграцию здорово упростит.

Answer (score 1):

Купите (возьмите у знакомых, у админа на работе) ещё один SATA кабель, подключите им SSD к компьютеру, отформатируйте его, перенесите данные.

Либо - вытащите из компьютера HDD, подключите SSD, установите ОС, поднимите сеть, снова соедините компьютер с ноутбуком, перенесите данные.